# c++ std::thread runtime depends on prior calls

Tags: c++, multithreading

**Disclaimer:** I am very, very new to doing thread-related stuff in C++. Probably I am missing something obvious.

Ok, so here is my problem: I am doing some Monte-Carlo integration in C++. The function, which performs the integration will be called a couple hundred times, therefore I decided to parallelize it for the potential speedup. Since the Integration itself consists of a large loop, I decided to split it into equal
parts and let each of these sub-loops run on a different thread. See this minimal working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <thread>

#define INTEGRATION_POINTS_3D 4e7

#define NUM_THREADS 4

double Psi(std::array<double,3> x, double sigma)
{
    return std::exp(-(x[0]*x[0]+x[1]*x[1]+x[2]*x[2])/(sigma*sigma) )
        + std::exp(-(x[0]*x[0]+x[1]*x[1]+x[2]*x[2])/(2*sigma*sigma) )
        + std::exp(-(x[0]*x[0]+x[1]*x[1]+x[2]*x[2])/(3*sigma*sigma) );
}

double NormPsiMC(double sigma, std::default_random_engine rng)
{
    double xmin(-4*sigma), xmax(4*sigma);
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> space_dist(xmin, xmax);

    static std::vector<std::thread> threads(NUM_THREADS);
    std::vector<double> res(NUM_THREADS, 0);
    for(int tid = 0; tid < NUM_THREADS; ++tid)
    {
        threads[tid] = std::thread(std::bind([&](int id){
            std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

            for(int i = 0; i < INTEGRATION_POINTS_3D/NUM_THREADS; ++i)
            {
                res[id] += std::abs(Psi(std::array<double,3>{{space_dist(rng),space_dist(rng),space_dist(rng)}}, sigma));
            }
            std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            std::cout << "In thread " << id << "\nI've spend "
                << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end-start).count() << " s in the loop." << std::endl;
        }, tid) );
    }

    double result(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        threads[i].join();
        result += res[i];
    }
    return std::pow(xmax-xmin,3)*result/INTEGRATION_POINTS_3D;
}

int main()
{
    double sigma(10);
    std::default_random_engine rng;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << NormPsiMC(sigma, rng) << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, for this I get for example the output

```
In thread 1                                                              
I've spent 2 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 2                                                              
I've spent 2 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 3                                                              
I've spent 2 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 0                                                              
I've spent 2 s in the loop.                                              
50289.1

In thread 2                                                              
I've spent 0 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 1                                                              
I've spent 0 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 3                                                              
I've spent 0 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 0                                                              
I've spent 2 s in the loop.                                              
50289.1
```

... and every successive run takes 0s. Ok, this is weird, since the first
5 calls of the threads are taking longer, even though they are doing the same. Aren't the threads not "warmed up yet"?

I know it sounds silly, but nevertheless, i tried to test it. I added a
function

```
void idle_func(void)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}
```

and in `int main()`

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads(NUM_THREADS);
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
{
    threads[i] = std::thread(idle_func);
    threads[i].join();
}
```

Now the output changes to

```
In thread 1                                                              
I've spent 0 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 2                                                              
I've spent 0 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 3                                                              
I've spent 2 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 0                                                              
I've spent 2 s in the loop.                                              
50289.1

In thread 2                                                              
I've spent 0 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 1                                                              
I've spent 0 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 3                                                              
I've spent 0 s in the loop.                                              
In thread 0                                                              
I've spent 0 s in the loop.                                              
50289.1
```

Alright, there are definitely fewer instances where the code needs longer. It seems that I am, at least somewhat, on the right track. However, adding more of the `idle_func`-thread calls does not further reduce this effect and honestly, this "fix" is quite shitty. On the other hand, I really have no clue what is going on.

Btw.: I am using `-Ofast`, however, this appears at all optimisation levels. Only for no optimisation, the effect is not visible. Yet, the overhead seems to depend strongly on the number of integration points; for `8e7` the times increases to 5s for the slow threads and 1s for the fast.

**Edit:** I've tested this now on two other machines and was not able to reproduce the afore mentioned syndromes. Therefore, I think this probably has something to do with my work machine.

Comment: The distributions and random number generators from the standard library are not thread-safe. You will need to synchronize access to them or provide a generator per thread.

Comment: @François Andrieux just tested it. However, the effect still occurs.

Comment: Interesting question, well done experiments and self contained test cases, that's the right way to start on StackOverflow! Here's my +1!

Comment: You probably want to seed your random number generator before using it.

Comment: @Galik sure. But for the example it did not matter.

Comment: I don't think you need `bind()` here, you should be able to use the lambda directly.

Comment: With your exact code I am unable to repeat your results using `GCC v7.2`

Comment: For me the same as Galik with VisualStudio 2015.
Always constant time

Comment: Cache is king. It's normal for the first time doing anything to take slightly longer ...